# How add columns from a list?

Tags: python, django, django-tables2

(This is my first post on StackOverFlow and it's a great ressource and community <3)

I develop a website and I use `django_tables2` to display my result.

My problem is that i have my table model here (very simple)...

```
#tables.py

class myTable(TableReport, ColumnShiftTable):

    column_default_show = ['select'];

    class Meta:
        attrs = {'class': 'table table-bordered table-striped table-condensed'};
```

and I want to display dynamically a set of columns...

```
#views.py

def visualiserGeneByHost(request):

    #Get the list of Host
    ReferenceList = exportdata();

    #Get a hash (in keys the name of the genes and in value an object with values and host name.
    geneByHostHash = exportGeneByHost(ReferenceList);

    data = [];

    for key in geneByHostHash:

       list=geneByIsolatHash.get(key);

       for element in list:

            data.append({'gene':key, element.Reference:element.pc_identity})

    table = ResistanceTable(data=data)

    return render(request,'visualisation/page_bootstrap_GeneByHost.html' , {'table':table} )
```

The `geneByHostHash` look likes this :

```
{'rrsH_[Escherichia coli]': [< X instance at 0x7f4abdcef440>, <X instance at 0x7f4abdcef488>, <X instance at 0x7f4abdcef8c0>], 'fusA1_[Klebsiella pneumoniae]': [<X instance at 0x7f4abdcef878>], ......}
```

...but I don't know how adding the columns because the list of columns is not stable.

```
#page_bootstrap_GeneByHost.html

<!-- Table loader -->
<div class="row">
<form action="{% url 'visualiserGeneByHost' %}" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}

    {% load django_tables2 %}
    {% render_table table %}

</form>
</div>
```

I will have a result like that table -> [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/slpG3.png)
I have already all the data like the name of the Genes, the values and the name of the each hosts.

I hope that I have been understandable.

**EDIT**

I look up with `extra_columns` arg in `django_tables2` but i have `__init__` conflict with `TableReport` & `ColumnShiftTable`. :/

**EDIT**

I resolve this problem like this:

## tables.py

```
class ResistanceTable(tables.Table):

    souche = tables.Column();
    column_default_show = ['souche']

    def __init__(self, data, newscolumns, *args, **kwargs):

        if newscolumns:

            for col in newscolumns:
                self.base_columns[col] = tables.Column(verbose_name=col)

        super(ResistanceTable, self).__init__( data, newscolumns, *args, **kwargs)


    class Meta:
        attrs = {'class': 'table table-bordered table-striped table-condensed'}
```

## view.py

```
#init a new table with data and news columns !!!!!
    table = ResistanceTable(data=data,newscolumns=geneList)
```

Comment: Hello @DalinDad, welcome to StackOverflow. Could you elaborate more what you want to achieve? Do you have a template you can show what you tried doing?

Comment: Thanks @Walucas for the correction. I have edited my post so i hope it's now better to understand.

Comment: Show us the real data and a full function in `views.py`. What does this function return? What template are you using to display the table? Btw, it's python. It means 2 things: you don't need semicolons at the end of lines + indentation matters (your `myTable` class is not properly indented).

Comment: Thanks @BUZZY for your comment. I edited my post. I hope it's most clear. And for the semicolons, i know that is not mandatory in python but i like this syntax.

Comment: whats the output you get from render_table?

Comment: @Walucas you mean a simple (print(render_table)) ?

Comment: @DalinDad on your template I meant

Comment: @Walucas I don't understand. `render_table` just rendering the table object. i am looking on functions like extra_columns but i dont find something that can resolve my problem.

Comment: Thats why I am asking. I want to understand what you want to achive. b/c looks like you dont get the columns from the output of the `render_table`

Comment: The `render_table` just render theses columns in `column_default_show` but i just put `select` field. I just want after init my table add new columns from a list of string (string are the names of the future columns) next to this last columns (`select`)